# Spaces between the elements MigLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, miglayout

Maybe some of you will be able to help me, because I'm sitting on this for a few hours and I do not know what to do. I checked the documentation several times, but with out any effect

I need to create java gui where the components A1, A2, A3 will be aligned to the left, the elements B1, B2, B3 will be aligned to the right.
TextArea will grow with the window, and the bottom will be something similar to the numeric keypad.

Problem number one:
Items not want to change when i change window size

Problem number two:
A large gap between the buttons

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZmKw.png

```
    package zad32;

    import javax.swing.*;
    import net.miginfocom.swing.*;
    public class MigTest extends JFrame {

      public MigTest() {
        setLayout(new MigLayout());

        add(new JButton("A1"));
        add(new JButton("A2"));
        add(new JButton("A2"));

        add(new JButton("B1"), "right align");
        add(new JButton("B2"), "right align");
        add(new JButton("B3"), "right align, wrap");

        add(new JScrollPane(new JTextArea(20,50)), "grow, span, wrap");

        add(new JButton("1"));
        add(new JButton("2"));
        add(new JButton("3"));
        add(new JTextField("To jest JTextField", 15), "span 3, right align, wrap");

        add(new JButton("4"));
        add(new JButton("5"));
        add(new JButton("6"));
        add(new JTextField("To jest JTextField", 15), "span 3, right align, wrap");

        add(new JButton("7"));
        add(new JButton("8"));
        add(new JButton("9"));
        add(new JTextField("To jest JTextField", 15), "span 3, right align, wrap");

        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MigTest();
      }

    }
```

Comment: Use multiple nested layouts.

Answer (score 0):

answer for gap:

```
font-size:0; must be added to parent element
```

alternatively, you can do:

```
setLayout(new MigLayout("gap rel 0", "grow"));
```

Comment: When i try
    setLayout(new MigLayout("gap rel 0", "grow")); i get error The constructor MigLayout(String, String) is undefined

Comment: When i change it to panel.setLayout(new MigLayout("gap rel 0", "grow", null)); it grows, but there is still big space between elements :(